# Retrieve dictionary from Sqlite in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am storing an NSMutableDictionary into a sqlite database.  I've succeeded in storing it.  My problem is retrieving it.  I want to retrieve the NSMutableDictionary as a whole and assign it to another NSMutableDictionary so I can start using it.

The below code allows me to retrieve a text data type and assign it to the addressField, but I can't figure out how to retrieve an NSMutableDictionary with data type blob from the database.

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
   NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)    sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
}
```

Im not sure how to initiate the NSMutableDictionary so I can use the  sqlite3_column_blob
function on it.

Here is my Save to database code.

```
            //This is the nsdictionary that Im going to save in the database
            NSMutableDictionary *thisTicket = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [thisTicket setValue:globalData.vehicleYear forKey:@"vehicleYear"];
            [thisTicket setValue:globalData.vehicleMake forKey:@"vehicleMake"];
            [thisTicket setValue:globalData.vehicleModel forKey:@"vehicleModel"];
            [thisTicket setValue:globalData.ticket forKey:@"ticketNumber"];

            //open database and save
            sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
            const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_ticketDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {

                NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                       @"INSERT INTO TICKETS (user, ticketnum, ticketinfo) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                                       [[PFUser currentUser]objectId], globalData.ticket, thisTicket];

                const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB, insert_stmt,
                                   -1, &statement, NULL);
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Added");

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_ticketDB);
            }
```

After I save, here is what my database look like (I use SqliteManager to view the database). Ticketinfo is the column that has my NSMutableDictionary (named thisTicket in above code).

I don't have enough reputation to add a picture yet.  Ill have earn some and then add it

Here is my code to retrieve the NSDictionary.

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tickets.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
}else{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_ticketDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ticketinfo FROM tickets WHERE user=\"%@\"",
                              [[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {


                NSUInteger blobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 5);
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 5) length:blobLength];

                NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData: data
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                          error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",dict);

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(_ticketDB);
    }
}
```

Im NSLogging the dict as its looping through the rows so I can see it but it displays null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlite3_column_blob  will gives you NSDictionary in the form of NSData:

```
NSUInteger blobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, colNo);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, colNo) length:blobLength];
```

then you have to convert it back to NSDictionary :

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization 
       JSONObjectWithData: data 
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves 
                    error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks V-Xtreme.  In not getting anymore errors but when I NSLog the dictionary to see whats in it afterwards, its null.  What does the 8 mean in your code?

Comment: I have edited my question . basically second parameter should be your column number . Just try it out .

Comment: Still getting null when I NSLog the dictionary.  Im going to post my full Save code, picture of what the database looks like after the save, and my retrieve code. Ill edit my original question with this code.

Comment: I cannot see the difference between the these 3 lines of asked question sample code and answered code. I am facing same issue today, did the same suggested in answer, but getting null. @V-Xtreme